# How to integerate drools with jbpm 5.4 process?

Tags: drools

Am new to JBPM.I need a example process of jbpm with drools integeration.Please post your answers ASAP

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to read [jBPM5 Developer Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/jboss-business-process-management-5-jave-developer-guide/book) book.

You can find the code sample of that book here: https://github.com/Salaboy/jBPM5-Developer-Guide/tree/1.0.Final/chapter_09

Hope it helps,